# iPhone Address book: How to select multiple contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts, addressbook

I would like to execute the same operation on multiple contact of the Address Book.
Is there an API available to allow multiple contacts selection from the Address Book ?

If it is not possible natively with iPhone SDK, is there any other alternative / library doing this simple thing ?

Answer (score 5):

You'll almost certainly have to do this yourself.  However, there are functions like [`ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3) which will get you a list of everyone in the address book.  From there it'd just be a matter of throwing that list into a tableview and providing the multiple-select capability.